# Cosh and Sinh analogs

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, special-functions, exponential-function

We know that 
$$\cosh{x}+\sinh{x}=e^x$$
and that his can be expressed as
$$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}+\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{(e^x+e^x)+(e^{-x}-e^{-x})}{2}=e^x$$
and this works out nicely because the $e^{-x}$ cancel.  Now consider a "higher order" cosh equation of the form 
$$C(x)=\frac{e^{\omega^0x}+e^{\omega^1 x}+e^{\omega^2x }}{3}$$
where $\omega^k$ are the 3rd roots of unity; $\omega^k=e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{3}}$.  I would like to devise an analagous expression
$$C(x)+S_1(x)+S_2(x)=e^x$$
with functions of the form $C$.  My first reaction was
$$S_1=\frac{e^{\omega^0x}-2e^{\omega^1 x}+e^{\omega^2x }}{3};  S_2=\frac{e^{\omega^0x}+e^{\omega^1 x}-2e^{\omega^2x }}{3}$$
and indeed
$$(C+S_1+S_2)(x)=\frac1{3}\left[(3e^{\omega^0 x})+(e^{\omega^1 x}-2e^{\omega^1 x}+e^{\omega^1 x})+(e^{\omega^2 x}+e^{\omega^2 x}-2e^{\omega^2 x})\right]=e^x$$
My intuition was that this was correct; since in the case of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, the 2nd roots of unity correspond to $1$ and $-1$.  But my second thought was that there was no need for subtraction of $2e^{\omega^k x}$ for $k=1,2$.  Perhaps there was a way to keep all the signs positive and find an $a,b$ such that 
$$e^{\omega^1 x}+e^{a\omega^1 x}+e^{b\omega^1 x}=0$$
$$e^{\omega^2 x}+e^{a\omega^2 x}+e^{b\omega^2 x}=0$$
I thought this would keep things a little more "symmetrical" and reduce the need for a $-2$ coefficient around the nontrivial roots of unity.  I tried some things to get values for $a,b$ but have been unsuccessful.  Should I just be happy with my original $S_1, S_2$ or are there choices for $a,b$ that would keep the symmetry?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exactly?

Comment: Studying and researching hypergeometric Bernoulli numbers, Appell sequences, came across a paper on compositional Bernoulli numbers and was seeing if there were ways to extend it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a symmetrical generalization for $n$th roots then define

$$C_{k,n}(z)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\zeta^n=1}\zeta^k e^{\zeta z}.$$

Then $C_{0,2}(z)=\cosh z$ and $C_{1,2}(z)=\sinh z$. Note that $C_{k,n}(z)=C_{0,n}^{(k)}(z)$.

In particular, for $n=3$, if $\omega$ is the cube root of unity in the upper half plane then

$$\begin{array}{lll} C_{0,3}(z) & = & \displaystyle \frac{e^z+e^{\omega z}+e^{\omega^2z}}{3} \\ C_{1,3}(z) & = & \displaystyle\frac{e^z+\omega e^{\omega z}+\omega^2 e^{\omega^2 z}}{3} \\
C_{2,3}(z) & = & \displaystyle \frac{e^z+\omega^2 e^{\omega z}+\omega e^{\omega^2z}}{3} \end{array}$$

---

There is an advanced viewpoint coming from representation theory. If we understand the group $G$ of complex $n$th roots of unity to act on a space of functions $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ (where a root of unity $\zeta$ acts by replacing a function $f(z)$ with $f(\zeta^{-1} z)$), then one may apply the **isotypical projectors** in order to decompose any function into its "constituents," and these are the isotypic components of the exponential function.

If one lets $\zeta$ be a primitive root of unity, then these are precisely the eigenvectors of the operator $f(z)\mapsto f(\zeta^{-1}z)$ (with eigenvalues the $n$th roots of unity) which combine to form the exponential function $\exp(z)$. One obtains these constituent parts with the kind of twisting-averaging operation you see in play in the definition of these $C_{k,n}(z)$s.

Comment: I was thinking as I was typing that the $-e^{-x}$ was better characterized by $-1\cdot e^{-1\cdot x}$.  I like this. Thanks

Comment: Real quick, in your summation you have $e^{\zeta x}$.  Did you mean $e^{\zeta^k x}$?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven $\zeta$ is an index of summation that varies over all $n$ solutions to $\zeta^n=1$. (Yes, you can do things like that.)

Comment: I see.  It took a second but it is clear.  Thank you for the second elaboration.

Comment: In effect, we are taking a discrete Fourier transform here.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Indeed! (Some call certain aspects of representation theory, "nonabelian fourier analysis," and I felt like being more general in my second section than perhaps I needed to be.)